# Jquery plugin using link or reference

Tags: jquery

I want to use jquery and put the jquery.js in static folder.

1st:

```
script type="text/javascript" src="{{STATIC_URL}}js/jquery.js"
```

2nd :

```
link href="{{STATIC_URL}}js/jquery.js"
```

it seems only 1st option is work for me, second not. however bootstrap can be linked by 2nd option.

Anyone could tell the logic?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

> 1st: script type="text/javascript" src="{{STATIC_URL}}js/jquery.js"
>   2nd : link href="{{STATIC_URL}}js/jquery.js" rel="stylesheet"

why you have

> rel="stylesheet"

Comment: sorry, but even without rel, link is still not working. can not find jquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
1st: script type="text/javascript" src="{{STATIC_URL}}js/jquery.js" 

2nd : link href="{{STATIC_URL}}js/jquery.js" rel="stylesheet"
```

In the second option you referencing the jquery.js file as if it were a stylesheet. Obviously that will not work, which is the intended behavior.

Have a look at these links. The 1st one shows you how to embed javascript: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_howto.asp

The second one shows you how to use css files: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/adding-css-to-html-with-link-embed-inline-and-import

Comment: thanks, but even if i remove rel, it still doesnt work.zzzz. I will edit the question. remove that rel.

Comment: it's not the rel that is causing your problem. The correct way to implement a javascript file is : <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script> you can use <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyles.css" media="screen" /> for css files and the sort.